# Adjust Height of <div> Tags Dynamically Generated By ng-if Directive

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Greetings and salutations friends.

Scenario: 
I am making a page which will generate invoices based on JSON info from the back-end. It uses ng-repeat on the containing divs and then ng-if inside on multiple p tags as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="thumb in responseArray" ng-if="responseArray.length >= 1" class="figures" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
            <p><b>{{thumb.supplier_name}}</b></p>
            <p class="stakedLabel">Staked:</p>
            <p class="staked">{{thumb.staked}}</p>
            <p class="returnsLabel">Returns:</p>
            <p class="returns"> {{thumb.returns}}</p>
            <p class="grossLabel">Gross: </p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length > 1" class="gross">{{thumb.gross}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartASingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartBSingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartA">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartB">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartC">{{thumb.theList[0][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartA">{{thumb.theList[1][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartB">{{thumb.theList[1][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartC">{{thumb.theList[1][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartA">{{thumb.theList[2][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartB">{{thumb.theList[2][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartC">{{thumb.theList[2][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartA">{{thumb.theList[3][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartB">{{thumb.theList[3][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartC">{{thumb.theList[3][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFive != '' && thumb.theList.length > 4" class="chargeDetailsFivePartA">{{thumb.theList[4][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFive != '' && thumb.theList.length > 4" class="chargeDetailsFivePartB">{{thumb.theList[4][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFive != '' && thumb.theList.length > 4" class="chargeDetailsFivePartC">{{thumb.theList[4][2]}}</p>                
        </div>
```

The problem is that I want the divs to ideally adjust in size based on their contents at run time, or failing that just be able to set two different heights dynamically. There are two overall options for how the divs will generate: one type will be considerably shorter which will be used when theList.length is 1, the other will be about twice the size roughly.

My current css is as follows:

```
   .figures {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        position: relative;
        height: 180px;
        top: -20px;
    }
```

I've tried a lot of different things like having no height, setting height to auto, setting overflow to auto, using the clearfix workaround and so forth.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up fixing it by creating a list for each type (meaning the length of the div) of record and then using ng-repeat on each list. This allowed me to set different classes for each type and thus different heights.

Bit of a workaround but works nice

```
<div ng-repeat="thumb in arrayOfOneTiers" ng-if="arrayOfOneTiers.length >= 1" class="figuresOneTier" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
            <p><b>{{thumb.supplier_name}}</b></p>
            <p class="stakedLabel">Staked:</p>
            <p class="staked">{{thumb.staked}}</p>
            <p class="returnsLabel">Returns:</p>
            <p class="returns"> {{thumb.returns}}</p>
            <p class="grossLabel">Gross: </p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length > 1" class="gross">{{thumb.gross}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartASingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartBSingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartA">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartB">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartC">{{thumb.theList[0][2]}}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="thumb in arrayOfTwoTiers" ng-if="arrayOfTwoTiers.length >= 1" class="figuresTwoTier" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
            <p><b>{{thumb.supplier_name}}</b></p>
            <p class="stakedLabel">Staked:</p>
            <p class="staked">{{thumb.staked}}</p>
            <p class="returnsLabel">Returns:</p>
            <p class="returns"> {{thumb.returns}}</p>
            <p class="grossLabel">Gross: </p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length > 1" class="gross">{{thumb.gross}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartASingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartBSingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartA">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartB">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartC">{{thumb.theList[0][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartA">{{thumb.theList[1][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartB">{{thumb.theList[1][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartC">{{thumb.theList[1][2]}}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="thumb in arrayOfThreeTiers" ng-if="arrayOfThreeTiers.length >= 1" class="figuresThreeTier" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
            <p><b>{{thumb.supplier_name}}</b></p>
            <p class="stakedLabel">Staked:</p>
            <p class="staked">{{thumb.staked}}</p>
            <p class="returnsLabel">Returns:</p>
            <p class="returns"> {{thumb.returns}}</p>
            <p class="grossLabel">Gross: </p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length > 1" class="gross">{{thumb.gross}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartASingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartBSingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartA">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartB">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartC">{{thumb.theList[0][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartA">{{thumb.theList[1][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartB">{{thumb.theList[1][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartC">{{thumb.theList[1][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartA">{{thumb.theList[2][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartB">{{thumb.theList[2][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartC">{{thumb.theList[2][2]}}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="thumb in arrayOfFourTiers" ng-if="arrayOfFourTiers.length >= 1" class="figuresFourTier" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
            <p><b>{{thumb.supplier_name}}</b></p>
            <p class="stakedLabel">Staked:</p>
            <p class="staked">{{thumb.staked}}</p>
            <p class="returnsLabel">Returns:</p>
            <p class="returns"> {{thumb.returns}}</p>
            <p class="grossLabel">Gross: </p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length > 1" class="gross">{{thumb.gross}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartASingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartBSingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartA">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartB">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartC">{{thumb.theList[0][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartA">{{thumb.theList[1][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartB">{{thumb.theList[1][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartC">{{thumb.theList[1][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartA">{{thumb.theList[2][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartB">{{thumb.theList[2][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartC">{{thumb.theList[2][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartA">{{thumb.theList[3][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartB">{{thumb.theList[3][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartC">{{thumb.theList[3][2]}}</p>
        </div>
        <div ng-repeat="thumb in arrayOfFiveTiers" ng-if="arrayOfFiveTiers.length >= 1" class="figuresFiveTier" layout="column" layout-align="center end">
            <p><b>{{thumb.supplier_name}}</b></p>
            <p class="stakedLabel">Staked:</p>
            <p class="staked">{{thumb.staked}}</p>
            <p class="returnsLabel">Returns:</p>
            <p class="returns"> {{thumb.returns}}</p>
            <p class="grossLabel">Gross: </p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length > 1" class="gross">{{thumb.gross}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartASingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.theList.length == 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartBSingleton">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartA">{{thumb.theList[0][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartB">{{thumb.theList[0][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsOne != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsOnePartC">{{thumb.theList[0][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartA">{{thumb.theList[1][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartB">{{thumb.theList[1][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsTwo != '' && thumb.theList.length > 1" class="chargeDetailsTwoPartC">{{thumb.theList[1][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartA">{{thumb.theList[2][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartB">{{thumb.theList[2][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsThree != '' && thumb.theList.length > 2" class="chargeDetailsThreePartC">{{thumb.theList[2][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartA">{{thumb.theList[3][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartB">{{thumb.theList[3][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFour != '' && thumb.theList.length > 3" class="chargeDetailsFourPartC">{{thumb.theList[3][2]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFive != '' && thumb.theList.length > 4" class="chargeDetailsFivePartA">{{thumb.theList[4][0]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFive != '' && thumb.theList.length > 4" class="chargeDetailsFivePartB">{{thumb.theList[4][1]}}</p>
            <p ng-if="thumb.chargeDetailsFive != '' && thumb.theList.length > 4" class="chargeDetailsFivePartC">{{thumb.theList[4][2]}}</p>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this css

```
  .figures {
        border-width: 2px;
        border-style: solid;
        border-color: black;
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        min-height: 180px;
        top: -20px;
    }
```